# There is at most one n such that $|X|=n$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

This question rises from a rather specific setup. For some $n\in\mathbb N$, write $|X|=n$ precisely when $\exists f:\{1,...,n\}\rightarrow X$ bijective. This is an "introductory" definition of cardinality, restricted to finite sets; here, of course, $X$ is just some set. With this notion, I am supposed to prove that there is at most one $n\in\mathbb N$ such that $|X|=n$ for an arbitrary set $X$. Intuitively, this makes perfect sense. The existence of such a bijection means there are precisely $n$ elements in $X$, so there cannot be two different numbers that describe the amount of elements. If the set $X$ is infinite, there is obviously not a single number in $\mathbb N$ that can describe the amount of elements in $X$.

What I am struggling with is finding a concise yet precise proof of this statement, working from the defintion above. I have had the following ideas:

1. To prove that there can be sets for which there is no such $n$, assume there is a bijection $g:\{1,...,n\}\rightarrow\mathbb N$ and deduce an absurdity.
2. Assuming there is such an $n$, suppose there are two bijections $f_1:\{1,...,n\}\rightarrow X$ and $f_2:\{1,...,m\}\rightarrow X$, for $m,n\in\mathbb N$, and show that $m=n$.

Proving the second statement would be easy if we "knew" that if there are two bijections $f:X\rightarrow Z$ and $g:Y\rightarrow Z$, then there is a bijection $h:X\rightarrow Y$. However, as this question is stated very early on in my course material, notably before this statement is even mentioned, I assume there should be some specific way to work without it, only using the notion of Injectivity, Surjectivity and Bijectivity, in addition to the basic set-operations. The same remark can be made about the first statement, too. In both cases, I have tried writing out some definitions to look for usefull structures, but it ended up in a mess.

Comment: Case 2: a bijection works both ways. Thus: $f : \{ 1,2,\ldots, n \} \to X$ and $g : X \to \{ 1,2,\ldots, m \}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose our finite set $X$ has two cardinalities $n $ and $n^*$ i.e. $|X|=n$ and $|X|=n^*$.

Since $X$ has $n$ elements, there exists a bijection $f$ of $\mathbb{N}_n$ onto $X$.

Also, since $X$ has $n^*$ elements, there exists a bijection $g$ of $\mathbb{N}_{n^*}$ onto $X$.

Now if we were to have $n>n^*$, then since compositions of bijections are bijections, we should have $$g^{-1}\circ f$$ is also a bijection from $\mathbb{N}_{n^*}$ onto $\mathbb{N}_n$, but this contradicts the [Pigeonhole Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle#Alternative_formulations). Argue similarly to rule out the possibility that $n<n^*$ and conclude $n=n^*$.

Note: $\mathbb{N}_m$ refers to the set $\{1,2,...,m\}$.